# SSIS how to pass a variable in a parameter

Tags: ssis

I created a package SSIS to have a property of a file (size of the file,date of creation of the file).In the input is the name of the file that I want to have the property  and in the output is the property of the file.To do this I created a script task in vb. The file property is stored in a variables.I want to deploy the package.My goal is I can execute the package like

exec dbo.PackageXXX XXX,@Param_size output,@Param_date_creation output;

How I can pass the value of a variables to the parameter output of the SSIS? What I need to do collect the file result in out put when I run the package?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do in the package execution command to populate output variables.   The usual "SSIS way" of doing this is to have the package write the results to a history table, which you can read at your convenience.