# Calling SSIS from Stored Procedure and Returning Variable Values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a question about how to return values from an SSIS project, that I'm calling from a stored procedure. Is it possible to return SSIS package variables (that I am using to store intermediate results/values/outputs for the SSIS processing) to the stored procedure that is calling the SSIS project in the SSISDB catalog?

Seems like it should be simple to get 'outputs' from an SSIS package call.  Passing parameters into SSIS is a breeze, and is clearly supported. But getting parameters/variables out seems like there is no support in SSIS for getting a parameter/variable as an SSIS output at all...

Comment: No not really. Normally it's done the other way around - the SSIS package calls a store procedure. What are you trying to do - this isn't a pattern that is often required. You can of course anything that has been written by the package into a table.

Comment: Thanks Nick,  I'm quite amazed that Microsoft never considered the need for Output parameters, especially when looking at SSIS as a programming language of sorts.  I actually have already resorted to a table, and possibly using files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507484/ssis-how-to-pass-a-variable-in-a-parameter

Comment: SSIS isn't a programming language. If you're using it as one then you're using the wrong tool. I mention it because a lot of people use this tool for the wrong reason. If you need to transfer data it doesn't automatically mean you need to use this tool. Under certain circumstances, pure T-SQL or C# is better at the job, particularly if you are using it as some kind of function.

Comment: Thanks Nick.   In this use case, we ended up with 2.5K lines of SQL, and by using an MDX script in SSIS we ended up with 20 lines of code that did the same thing, and is a lot more maintainable.  Having used a variety of Graphical Programming Languages over the years, they certainly can save a lot of development time in certain applications, as applied to in this case.  I agree, SSIS is certainly not for all applications.

Comment: Well that's definitely a win!